# Resultset to excel data not populating

Tags: java

The headers of the table are generated but not the data.
I tried everything but somehow either the data is haphazard or blank

detail: query to excel

How to format below code?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;


public class QA2Excel {

     /**
     * @param paramArrayOfString
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString)
        throws Exception
      {
        try
        {
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          String str1 = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@indlin076:1521:VELABP1";
          String str2 = "VELDB2";
          String str3 = "VELDB2";
          Connection localConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(str1, str2, str3);
          HSSFWorkbook localHSSFWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
          localConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
          Statement localStatement = localConnection.createStatement();
          String str4 = "VELDBO2";
          String str5 = "VELDBO2";
          String str6 = "@DB14";
          String filename="C://Users/debankad/Desktop/empha.xls";

          FileReader localFileReader = new FileReader("C://Users/debankad/Desktop/QueriesOfQa.txt");


        BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(localFileReader);
          String str11;
          String paramString= "";


          //StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

          while ((str11 = localBufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
          { 
              if (str11.startsWith("--EPC")){
                  paramString = str11.replace("--","").toUpperCase();
                  System.out.println("PARAMSTRING" + paramString);
              }

              if (!str11.endsWith(";")){
              System.out.println(str11);
              String str14 = str11;

              if (str11 != null && !str11.isEmpty() && !str11.startsWith("--") && !str11.startsWith("//")){

                  paramString = paramString + 1;
                ResultSet localResultSet = localStatement.executeQuery(str11);
              int i = recordCountinResultSet(localResultSet);

              HSSFSheet localHSSFSheet = localHSSFWorkbook.createSheet(paramString);
              HSSFRow localHSSFRow = localHSSFSheet.createRow(0);
              ResultSetMetaData localResultSetMetaData = localResultSet.getMetaData();
              for (int k = 0; k < localResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); k++){
                localHSSFRow.createCell((short)k).setCellValue(localResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(k + 1));
              for (int k1 = 1; localResultSet.next(); k1++)
              {
                  localHSSFRow = localHSSFSheet.createRow((short)k1);
                for (int j = 0; j < localResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); j++)
                  localHSSFRow.createCell((short)j).setCellValue(localResultSet.getString(j + 1));
              }
              }
              FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(filename);
              localHSSFWorkbook.write(fileOut);
              fileOut.close();
              System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");


              if (i == 0)
              {
                System.out.println("QA Passed");
              }
              else if (i >= 1)
              {
                  System.out.println("QA Failed");
              }
              else
              {
                System.out.println("No such Query");
              }
              }
          }


          //selectTableCreation(localStatement,localFileReader);

        //  String str8 = str2.substring(str2.lastIndexOf(" "), str2.length()).trim().toUpperCase();
          //  System.out.println(str8);


          }} catch (Exception E){
        E.printStackTrace();    
        }
        }


@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static List selectTableCreation(Statement paramStatement, FileReader paramFileReader)
{
  ArrayList<ResultSet> localArrayList = new ArrayList<ResultSet>();
  try
  {
    BufferedReader localBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(paramFileReader);
    String str1;

    while ((str1 = localBufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
      String str2 =  str1;

      try
      {
        ResultSet localResultSet = paramStatement.executeQuery(str2);
        System.out.println("Result Set Obtained");
        localArrayList.add(localResultSet);

      }
      catch (Exception localException2)
      {
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception localException1)
  {
    System.out.println("Exception caught as::" + localException1.getMessage());
  }
  return localArrayList;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void writeToFile(HSSFWorkbook paramHSSFWorkbook, ResultSet paramResultSet, String paramString)
throws Exception
{
HSSFSheet localHSSFSheet = paramHSSFWorkbook.createSheet(paramString);
HSSFRow localHSSFRow = localHSSFSheet.createRow(0);
ResultSetMetaData localResultSetMetaData = paramResultSet.getMetaData();
for (int i = 0; i < localResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++)
  localHSSFRow.createCell((short)i).setCellValue(localResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1));
for (int i = 1; paramResultSet.next(); i++)
{
  localHSSFRow = localHSSFSheet.createRow((short)i);
  for (int j = 0; j < localResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); j++)
    localHSSFRow.createCell((short)j).setCellValue(paramResultSet.getString(j + 1));
}}

public static int recordCountinResultSet(ResultSet paramResultSet)
{
  int i = 0;
  try
  {
    while (paramResultSet.next())
      i++;
  }
  catch (Exception localException)
  {
    System.out.println("Exception obtained as" + localException.getMessage());
  }
  return i;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have ended a parentheses at wrong position.

Try this and it should work:

```
for (int k = 0; k < localResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); k++)
{
  localHSSFRow.createCell((short)k).setCellValue(localResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(k + 1));
}          //This should end here
for (int k1 = 1; localResultSet.next(); k1++)
{
  localHSSFRow = localHSSFSheet.createRow((short)k1);
  for (int j = 0; j < localResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); j++)
  {
     localHSSFRow.createCell((short)j).setCellValue(localResultSet.getString(j + 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it giving any exception?